# Create a land mask from latitude and longitude arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cartopy

Given latitude and longitude arrays, I'm tryin to genereate a land_mask, an array of the same size that tells whether a coordinate is land or not.

```
lon=np.random.uniform(0,150,size=[1000,1000])
lat=np.random.uniform(-90,90,size=[1000,1000])

from global_land_mask import globe
land_mask=globe.is_land(lat,lon)
```

This is a very efficient method to create land mask if all values are defined. But if some values in lat or lon are masked or are nan values, it throws an error.

I've tried to use for loops to avoid that error but it's taking almost 15-20 minutes to run. I've to run it on an array with 3000×3000 elements, some of which are masked.

What would be a better way for generating land mask for arrays with masked/nan values?

Comment: This minimal example works for me. Can you remove the nan or masked coordinates first? Or build a mask of them and pass it in? Where are your lat, lon values from?

Comment: @GeoMonkey I think some more information would be useful. My actual lat and lon arrays do not come masked, they have a fill value (327.67) which is used for masking them later. Now, I can't pass a lat or lon=327.67 into the is_land function. So what you are saying is I create a mask (say nan_mask) using fill value, but do not apply it on lat/lon arrays. Replace fill value with say 0, pass the arrays to is_land and create a land mask. Then apply the nan_mask on it. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Pixel_Bear Right. I think that would work.

Comment: yes, I think that's basically it. But I would replace the 327.67 with np.nans and then use np.ma to pass a mask into the globe.is_land() function. I'll do some testing and post something

Comment: @GeoMonkey " use np.ma to pass a mask into the globe.is_land()", this part I'm unable to do right now. It'd be interesting to see how it's done.

Comment: @Pixel_Bear ok, so I can't pass a mask into the function. I think a solution may be to just replace them with values way outside your study domain (if possible, e.g. (-90, 0)) and then mask the arrays you get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so it seems `globe.is_land(y,x)` doesn't take a masked array. An equitable solution would be to use a coord outside your domain (if possible). So:

```
lon[lon==327.67] = 170
lat[lat==327.67] = -90

from global_land_mask import globe
land_mask=globe.is_land(lat,lon)

masked = np.where((lat==-90)|(lon==170), False, land_mask)
```

Alternatively, you could mask the values prior to passing them in:

```
lat_mask = np.where(lat==326.67, np.nan, lat)
lon_mask = np.where(lon==326.67, np.nan, lon)

master_mask = np.where((lat_mask==np.nan)|(lon_mask==np.nan), False, True)

lat[master_mask]==True 
lon[master_mask]==True 

from global_land_mask import globe
land_mask=globe.is_land(lat,lon)
```

The second solution will change (flatten) your lat/lon arrays but does not require you to find an area outside of your domain

Comment: I think I'm getting it. If land_mask==True, it applies, it's land. However, if land_mask==False, it doesn't mean sea/ocean. It can also mean that lat|lon==327.67 there. I got confused because I was trying to create an array with True(land), False(ocean), np.nan values(lat|lon==327.67), but different datatypes are not allowed. Thank you for the answer.